# azure webapp to webjob SOAP connection

Tags: rest, azure, soap, webjob

Need to make a SOAP connection from .php code running as a webapp to a c++ console mode application that is looking for a SOAP connection on a given port while running as a webjob fired off from a batch file.

in php the call looks like this and does not work:
$this->m_webservice_location="http://localhost:8080";

The error that comes back is:
Error from AddressPro SOAP: Could not connect to host

Any ideas what to try or how to gather the address that will hit the webjob?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure WebJob cannot listen on tcp ports.
You can use web sockets to communicate between web app and webjob, for example with signal-r: http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-from-azure-webjob-with-signalr

You can also communicate using the file-system by writing to a file under `d:\home\...` and listening to changes on that file.